# log4j/log4cxx : exclusive 1 to 1 relation between logger and appender

Tags: java, c++, log4j, log4cxx

Using the xml configuration of log4cxx (which is identical in configuration to log4j).
I want to have a certain logger output exclusively to a specific appender (have it the only logger which outputs to that appender).

I found that it's possible to bind a logger to a specific appender like this:

```
<logger name="LoggerName">
    <level value="info"/>
   <appender-ref ref="AppenderName"/>
</logger>
```

but it that logger still outputs to the root appender because I have this standard piece in the conf file:

```
<root>
   <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   <appender-ref ref="OtherAppender"/>
</root>
```

How can I exclude that logger from the root logger?
in other words, how do I configure the log such that all loggers inherit the appenders of the root logger except a specific logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the following piece of configuration for this:

```
<logger name="TRACER" additivity="false">
    <level value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
</logger>
```

All loggers with a name that starts with `TRACER` will log to the appender `DebugAppender`. For more info, check [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) or [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Additivity="false" means messages to this logger will not propogate up the loggers hierarchy so it will not print anything to the root logger.

Comment: I already saw that, and realized that it's not sufficient. re-read the question, I updated it.

Comment: Ah, that's more difficult, will try to find a solution (if there is any).

Comment: aha, got it. additivity="false" on the logger.